# How to bring Quartz scheduler to standby

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have quartz job implementation using spring. My scheduler works fine and jobs are getting executed perfectly.
My question is how to bring this scheduler to standby? So that no jobs gets triggered once I decide to bring the scheduler to standby mode.
Below is the job class

```
public class MyJobClass extends  QuartzJobBean  {
//my job logic
}
```

Snippet from applicationContext_Scheduler.xml

```
<bean name="myJobBean"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
<property name="jobClass" value="MyJobClass" />
</bean>         
<bean id="rsHourlyJobCronTrigger"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="myJobBean" />                       
<property name="cronExpression" value="00 0/1 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the scheduler bean in xml. I'd make it programatically as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzSchedulerConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Bean
  public JobFactory jobFactory() {
    ApplicationContextHolder jobFactory = new ApplicationContextHolder();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setSchedulerName("Quartz Scheduler");
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory());
    return factory;
  }
}

@Component
public final class ApplicationContextHolder extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static ApplicationContext context;

  private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
    beanFactory = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    context = ctx;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
    final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
    beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
    return job;
  }

  public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
  }
}
```

This will create your quartz scheduler bean that is application context aware allowing you to autowire spring objects into your quartz jobs.

Then create some Scheduling service like:

```
@Service
public class SchedulerService {

  @Autowired
  private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory;

  private Scheduler scheduler;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
  }

  public void standBy() throws Exception {
    if (scheduler != null && !scheduler.isInStandbyMode()) {
      scheduler.standby();
    }
  }
}
```

Then add other methods that you need for scheduling.

Comment: Thanks Issac. I used the "SchedulerFactoryBean" to get the scheduler object to controlled the 'start' and 'standby' modes